# What's the idea?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> They are not isotopes. They are not ions. What are they?

Comment: I proposed an edit that removes the filler sentence. Feel free to reject/rollback if the filler sentence is important to the puzzle!

Comment: removing the chemistry tag for the time being, feel free to add it back if needed. thanks and nice riddle!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, not sure if the chemistry tag should be there, as the answer is, as the riddle explains

> “Not ions”,

i.e.

> NOTIONS

This fits the title as

> A notion is an idea.